# Efficent Way to Move Records Between Tables Based on Last Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table that tracks the relationship between various attributes, and the dates when they occur. I want to look at how the relationships between the fields change for each entity. As part of this analysis I want to move the records where the relationships have ended by a certain date.

If the data looked something like this:

```
id | FieldOne | FieldTwo | FieldThree |  DataDate 
---------------------------------------------------
01 |    A     |    A     |    A       | 2000-01-01
01 |    A     |    A     |    A       | 2000-01-02
01 |    A     |    A     |    A       | 2000-01-03
01 |    A     |    A     |    A       | 2000-01-04
01 |    A     |    A     |    B       | 2000-01-05
02 |    A     |    C     |    C       | 2000-01-01
02 |    A     |    C     |    C       | 2000-01-02
02 |    A     |    D     |    C       | 2000-01-03
02 |    A     |    D     |    C       | 2000-01-04
02 |    A     |    D     |    C       | 2000-01-05
03 |    C     |    A     |    D       | 2000-01-01
03 |    C     |    A     |    D       | 2000-01-02
03 |    C     |    A     |    D       | 2000-01-03
03 |    C     |    A     |    D       | 2000-01-04
03 |    C     |    A     |    D       | 2000-01-05
```

I want to take the "closed" records, and study/analyse them.

So, if my cut-off date was 2000-01-05, then I'd be want remove all the AAA records for patient 01, but not the AAB record, which is still "active." Also, I'd want the ACC records for patient 02, but not the ADC records, and none of patient 03's records. The "active" records should be left in place so that the other processes that gather data can still write subsequent records for the same patients to the same table.

The actual table has nine columns, all of which are varchars, or varying lengths.

At the moment I'm doing it by finding all the ended relationships, then doing an ugly join.

```
SELECT id, FieldOne, FieldTwo, FieldThree
INTO Closed
FROM DataTable
GROUP BY id, FieldOne, FieldTwo, FieldThree
HAVING MAX( DataDate ) < '2001-01-05'

DELETE d.*
OUTPUT deleted.* 
INTO OutputTable
FROM DataTable d
INNER JOIN Closed c
ON d.Id = c.Id
AND (d.FieldOne = c.FieldOne
  OR (d.FieldOne IS NULL
  AND c.FieldOne IS NULL))
AND (d.FieldTwo = c.FieldTwo
  OR (d.FieldTwo IS NULL
  AND c.FieldTwo IS NULL))
AND (d.FieldThree = c.FieldThree
  OR (d.FieldThree IS NULL
  AND c.FieldThree IS NULL))
```

I feel like there is probably a better (faster, and more elegant) way to do this, but when I use EXISTS it returns all the records, not the subset I want.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: There might be a better way to do this...but what are your trying to do?

Comment: Can you show some sample data/schemas and expand your question based on that?

Comment: id is not unique , date is not unique nothing is unique !!!

Comment: The id + date is unique.

Answer (score 1):

This selects rows where the combinations of the first four columns have at least one record on or after the cutoff date:

```
select dt.*
from datatable dt
where exists (select 1
              from datatable dt2
              where dt.id = dt2.id and
                    dt.field1 = dt2.field1 and
                    dt.field2 = dt2.field2 and
                    dt.field3 = dt2.field3 and
                    dt.datadate >= '2001-01-05'
             );
```

If the values can have `NULL`s, then the comparisons need to take that into account.